# Proving continuity of a multivariable function by "reducing" it to a single variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

My goal is to examine the continuity of a certain multivariable function. In that regard, (mainly because my math in the specific area is dusty) I find it somewhat tricky to either prove or disprove that property in the *N*-diensional space. However, I have come up with the following idea:

---

let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be the function that I want to examine at some point $(x_0, y_0)$.

Now I am using the following two functions $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ and $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ so that I can write function $f$ as:
$$ f(x,y) = h(g(x,y)),\quad \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2
$$
I also know that function $g$ is indeed continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

My assumption is that I can examine the continuity of $h$ at $x' = g(x_0,y_0)$ in order to decide the continuity of $f$ at $(x_0,y_0)$   - a much easier task. In mathimatical notation, I guess what I mean is:
$$
\lim_{(x,y)->(x_0,y_0)} f(x,y) = f(x_0, y_0) \quad \iff \\ \lim_{x->g(x_0,y_0)}h(x) = h(g(x_0,y_0))
$$

---

**Actual Questions:**
 1. Is my assumption correct?
 2. If not, maybe do either of $\Rightarrow$ or $\Leftarrow$ hold? (Because if one of those holds then I can use the above to only prove or only disprove accoridnlgy.)
 3. Does the same hold for proving/disproving differentiability as well?
 4. Under what conditions do any of those hold for a (finite) sum of $h,g$ functions, i.e. $f(x,y) = h_1(g_1(x,y)) + h_2(g_2(x,y)) + ... + h_k(g_k(x,y))$

---

Note: I can actually post my original function and the transformation if the question is too broad or the answers depend greatly on the actual $f,g$ and $h$ definitions. However I believe a more general question may help more people find it and also make it easier to be understood.

Comment: We know that the composition of continuous functions is continuous.  So it suffices to show that $g(x,y)$ is continuous at $\xi_0 = (x_0,y_0)$.  That is that $\lim_{\xi \rightarrow \xi_0} g(\xi) = g(\xi_0)$.  Also note that showing that the derivative exists at $x_0$ is a sufficient, but not necessary condition for continuity.  That is differentiability implies continuity but not the converse.  For an example see $f(x) = |x|$.  This is continuous at $0$, and in fact Lipschitz continuous at $0$, but not differentiable there. *(continued)*

Comment: Also note a vector valued function is continuous if it is continuous in all its arguments

Comment: @GeauxMath First of all, thank you for responding. Now, I am fully aware about how differentiability implies continuity but not the other way around. Reading back my post, I think I was indeed looking for the property of compositions of continuous functions being continuous. I also take it, that in your first comment you meant to say that it suffices to show that $h(x)$ is continuous and not $g(x,y)$, as I already mentioned that $g$ is indeed continuous.

Comment: yes, you are correct

Comment: Cheers. If you would like to modify your comment to an answer, I am willing to accept it

Comment: To add to @GeauxMath's comment, the continuity of a composition of continuous functions is only one direction of your $\iff$. The other direction might not be true. For example, if $g(x_0,y_0) = a$ and $f(x,y) \geq a$, then $h$ can have a discontinuity at $a$. If $h(x)$ is continuous for $x > a$, $f$ would still be continuous.

Comment: Indeed, I understood that far. To be specific, all of my points are now answered. But I wouldn't like to answer it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for closure, I am answering myself in case it helps anyone else. Merit goes to @GeauxMath and @Todor Markov for providing answers in comments.

We can answer mainly by using the following proposition:

> A composition of continuous functions is continuous

In detail:

1. My assumption is **incorrect** as a whole
2. The $\Leftarrow$ direction holds by using the above proposition. The opposite is not true in every case. As a counter example

   > If $g(x_0,y_0)=a$ and $f(x,y)≥a$, then $h$ can have a discontinuity at a. If $h(x)$ is continuous for $x>a$, $f$ would still be continuous.
3. The corresponding property applies also to differentiable functions, so we can only prove that $f$ is differentiable that way, but not disprove it.
4. Again, by using that proposition we can extend our statements to that specific case, so we can prove continuity and differentiability of $f$ but not disprove. A counter example here would be a case where $h_1$ and $h_2$ are not continuous, but by adding them, their discontinuities "cancel out".